# How to use "exports" to export a single variable (a counter) in JavaScript ES5

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to export a single variable that I will increase. My TypeScript example works very well:

main.ts

```
import { myFirstFunction, mySecondFunction, counter } from "./functions";

function main()
{
    console.log("main");
    myFirstFunction();
    mySecondFunction();
    console.log(`counter = ${counter}`);
}

main();
```

functions.ts

```
export let counter = 0;

export function myFirstFunction(): void
{
    console.log("my first function");
    counter++;
}

export function mySecondFunction(): void
{
    console.log("my second function");
    counter++;
}
```

Output:

```
main
my first function
my second function
counter = 2
```

But how to translate this example to ES5 and Browserify? I do not want to export an object because I do not want to use a prefix like `counterInfo.counter`. I want to use `counter`. But when I translate this example I get `counter = 0`:

main.js

```
var { myFirstFunction, mySecondFunction, counter } = require("./functions");

function main()
{
    console.log("main");
    myFirstFunction();
    mySecondFunction();
    console.log("counter = " + counter);
}

window.onload = main();
```

functions.js

```
exports.counter = 0;

function myFirstFunction()
{
    console.log("my first function");
    exports.counter++;
}

function mySecondFunction()
{
    console.log("my second function");
    exports.counter++;
}

exports.myFirstFunction = myFirstFunction;
exports.mySecondFunction = mySecondFunction;
```

Output:

```
main
my first function
my second function
counter = 0
```

Comment: try this `exports.this.counter++;`

Comment: Error: `functions.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'counter' of undefined`

Comment: If I add `this` here `exports.this.counter = 0;` I get another error: `functions.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'counter' of undefined`

Comment: is it possible to change `exports.counter++` to return `counter++` and put output of  `myFirstFunction` to counter variable ?

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot do that. You can either a) create a getter and setter function, that way you can at least use `counter()` instead of `counter`, or create an actual global (and pollute the global namespace) by simply doing `counter = 0;` in one script and logging it in another.

Comment: Chris, thanks! The second way is a solution for me. I wanted a global variable for whole project without prefix like `global`, or parentheses. I know that global variables are bad. But I just need to initialize Ammo.js and WebGL in one place and use `Ammo` and `gl` variables in the rest project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris wrote the solution in comments. I wanted a global variable for whole project without prefix like `global`, or parentheses. I know that global variables are bad. But I just need to initialize Ammo.js and WebGL in one place and use `Ammo` and `gl` variables in the rest project files. `counter` is just for example.

main.js

```
var { myFirstFunction, mySecondFunction } = require("./functions");

function main()
{
    console.log("main");
    myFirstFunction();
    mySecondFunction();
    console.log("counter = " + counter);
}

window.onload = main();
```

functions.js

```
counter = 0;

function myFirstFunction()
{
    console.log("my first function");
    counter++;
}

function mySecondFunction()
{
    console.log("my second function");
    counter++;
}

exports.myFirstFunction = myFirstFunction;
exports.mySecondFunction = mySecondFunction;
```